# toxi tagging system, how to query the table to get unique results

Tags: mysql, database-design, tags, tagging

I use following database schema for a tagging system. it is a mildly customized toxi solution.

Tables:

```
Tags { tag_id, tag_name }
Tagmap { id, topic_type, topic_id, tag_id
Topics { topic_id, etc. }
```

If I want to get topics that match given tags the subject_type = 1. This is because I need to be more flexible and also want to use tags for other things.

This is my current query to get related topics based on their tags. The problem with this is that the results aren't unique. If there are several tags linked to a topic i get duplicate topics in the resultset.

The query is cutted to the minimum. Depending on the options there are some variations and optimizations etc. But i could figure this out on my own after I got a helping hand.

```
SELECT tm.id, tm.subject_id, topic.channel_id, topic.title, channel.privacy, channel.name
FROM tagmap tm
INNER JOIN topics topic
ON topic.id = tm.subject_id
INNER JOIN user_channels channel
ON channel.id = topic.channel_id
AND channel.privacy < 2
AND tm.TagID IN ('.$this->_sqlTagIds.')
AND tm.SubjectTypeID = 1
ORDER BY tm.id
DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The problem:

if one topic is tagged with several tags that occur in the searchtagids the topic is listed several times. So what I search for is a way to extract the subject_ids only once. Disctinct doesn't work because I need the tagmapid ( tm.id ) which is unique for every row.

Help would be nice. Thanks.

Edit: Query the table for topics based on tags and check if the privacy for the channel the topic belongs to is lower than 2.

PS: This query is for topics only. The tagmap table is shared. But I only need the query for topics.

Comment: What's the difference between a subject and a topic? What does the `id` column do? What are the "searchtagids"

Comment: the subject id is in this case the topic id. the subjecttype for topics = 1, For channles 2 etc. I change this.

Comment: if i would query channels based on tags the subject id would be the channel id.

Comment: Topics, channels, users, blogs, maybe posts etc. At least 4-5.

Comment: I think it was less confusing before the edit :-( I still don't understand what the tagmap.id is for - I never understood why toxi used it either :-(

Comment: PS: This query is for topics only. The tagmap table is shared. But I only need the query for topics.

Comment: _"The tagmap table is shared."_ - Using "generic" (aka. "polymorphic") foreign keys is an anti-pattern.